# Django admin tool broken?

Tags: django, django-admin

I've installed django on OS X 10.9.5 using pip, and everything worked great for a day.  I fired it up the next day and the tool seems to be broken.

Now, any command I issue aside from "startproject" fails with the following output.  I've tried starting a totally clean project, and I get the same thing.

```
$ django-admin manage.py check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 182, in fetch_command
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Not sure how helpful it is, since this is a fresh project, but here's the output from manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testdjango.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I've tried uninstall/reinstalling django.  Where should I look next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You should either type

```
django-admin check
```

or

```
python manage.py check
```

That being said; `django-admin` is only useful when creating the project. You should use the `manage.py` script for project-specific tasks. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/):

> Generally, when working on a single Django project, it’s easier to use manage.py than django-admin. If you need to switch between multiple Django settings files, use django-admin with DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or the --settings command line option.

Comment: Ah man, looks like I was a victim of "staring at it too long"!  Thanks :)